# JWPlayer shows Live Broadcast message on video

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I'm using JWplayer to play video stored in AWS S3 Bucket, but on playing video "Live Broadcast" message is displayed in left side bottom of video, check this image [image: Check this image]

i want to remove this message, any help will be appreciated.

MY Code:

**jwplayer("my-video").setup({
'playlist': obj
});**

where **obj** contains video file url and title.

Comment: theres no built in function to remove that i think it can be hide using css

Comment: why its showing live broadcast since the video is played from s3